# In Emacs how do I show the first 79 columns of a line in their own colour?

Tags: faces

I am using the Emacs package [visual-fill-column](https://github.com/joostkremers/visual-fill-column) to centre text and wrap it at 79 columns. Can I get these 79 columns to be shown in a colour different from the rest of the window?

Here is the relevant snippet from  my `init.el` file.

```lisp
(use-package visual-fill-column
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq visual-fill-column-width 79
        visual-fill-column-center-text t)
  :config
  (global-visual-line-mode)
  (global-visual-fill-column-mode))
```

Comment: Maybe [this EmacsWiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillColumnIndicator) will help, with similar things.

Comment: Thanks, Drew. The fill column indicator is my current work around. But there must be a way of showing all 79 columns in a particular colour.